# Disable compton/picom on regolith

Tags: i3-wm, compton

How can I disable compton/picom in Regolith 1.6 (the i3wm "desktop")?

Comment: What is easiest for you may not be easiest for someone else, so this would be an opinion based question which is not supported on this site. Perhaps change the question to just read "how disable compton", but even if I do not use i3, I am pretty sure this is disabled by commenting out the line that starts it up in the i3 config file.